# How to return a string that shows on multiple lines in console in javascript?

Tags: javascript, console, return, newline, line-breaks

If i do something like:

```
console.log('a'+ '\n' + 
            'b'+  '\n' + 
            'c');
```

I will get in console:

```
`a
 b
 c`
```

but if i try to return it such as:

```
function letter() {
return 'a'+ '\n' + 
       'b'+  '\n' + 
       'c';
}
letter();
```

it prints out `'a\nb\nc'`. how do i get the return to be the same as what it is in console.log only using the return statement?

it prints out fine in google developer console but i am using a console from repl.it so i guess it depends on how that console is formatted?

Comment: `console.log(letter());` Also, your second code snippet doesn't print anything (unless you're typing directly into the console)

Comment: must depend on the browser - both codes produce Identical output in firefox (and why is the format of console output important at all)

Comment: i am trying to do it without using console.log at all. just with the return statement itself.

Comment: which browser? and why is it important?

Comment: it's not a browser just a console in an environment on a website, it's just a javascript problem that wants me to print each of them on a new line

Comment: This question makes no sense. The only way to print something is to use `console.log` (or `console.error` etc.)

Comment: i can do letter(); and it will return 'a\nb\nc', im not using console.log and it gives me something back in the console?

Comment: You will have to explain more about how you're running the file, because that's not standard behavior.

Comment: sorry the website is repl.it and i can see that it works fine in google console

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine at least in Firefox and Chrome.

console.log(letter()); should do exactly what you want.

If you are running into an issue, I would guess that it is because of your browser. Try in another browser.

update: i see your response "it's not a browser just a console in an environment on a website, it's just a javascript problem that wants me to print each of them on a new line".

Certainly, in a normal browser your code is fine. Maybe on this site, they planned you to solve this in a different mannor. This could be a bug.

Comment: i am trying to do it without using console.log, just the return statement. i'm using console.log in the first place to show what it should look like but i am not sure if that is relevant even

Comment: ahh where is the website? Send me a link.

Comment: website is repl.it

Comment: Dude.. haha. send me a link to that puzzle. I am not going through the whole site.

Comment: well you could just type that in the developer console for any problem? also im not sure if you can access mine but it would be https://repl.it/student/submissions/622164

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```js
function letter() {
return "a\nb\nc";
}
console.log(letter());
```

It requires double quotes

Comment: It doesn't require double quotes.

Comment: trying to do this without using console.log sorry